# Backbone: need help passing a URL to a self-invoking function

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I was given this block of code to work with from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512551/backbone-console-log-returning-collection-and-undefined):

```
;(function(){

    var mythings = {};

    function initializer($, _, Backbone, tableModel){
        return Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: 'main-contact',  <!-- this used to be this.url.
            model: tableModel,
            initialize: function(models, options) {
               this.fetch();
            }
        });
    }

    define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'models/tableModel'
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, tableModel) {
        if (!mythings.tablesCollection){
            // this will be done on first run.
            mythings.tablesCollection = initializer($, _, Backbone, tableModel);
        }
        // all others will just return same exact instance of collection class
        return mythings.tablesCollection;
    });

})();
```

First, what does the semicolon at the beginning of the block mean?  Second, I need to pass in a URL at runtime in my route, like this:

```
var t = new tablesCollection(null, { url: 'main-contact'} );
```

This is what I've been doing up until now, when I'm trying to recreate this project as AMD.  How can I pass in the URL at runtime, like this into the block of self-invoking code?

EDIT:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tableModel',
    'collections/tablesCollection',
    'views/tablesView'
], function($, _, Backbone, tableModel, tablesCollection, tablesView) {
    require(['collections/tablesCollection'], function(tablesCollection) {
        var t = new tablesCollection(null, {url: 'main-contact'});
            var tables = new tablesView({ collection: t, template: 'main-contact-template'});
            $('#web-leads').html(tables.render().el);
    });
```

});

Comment: If you plan on calling it at runtime, give it a name, and don't invoke it immediately.

Comment: @sehummel, self-invoking functions are not necessary with AMD, because the `define` callback already scopes your module. I believe the user in the other post was just trying to make an example, not that you should use an IIFE.

Comment: I wondered why he did it since it was completely out of place being self-invoking.

Comment: leading `;` is a habitual preventive measure that makes concatenation of scripts a bit more brainless affair. It's part of my self-invoking template in SublimeText. It's just a part of my best practices.   The self-exec was needed because two variables are introduced outside of the `define` scope and I did not want them to become global by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, as other commenters have noted, you don't need the extra "module pattern" wrapping; your code can be simplified to:

```
define(['jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'models/tableModel'
], function($, _, Backbone, tableModel) {
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'main-contact',  //<-- this used to be this.url.
        model: tableModel,
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.fetch();
        }
    });
});
```

Then, elsewhere, you can do:

```
require(['path/to/TablesCollection', function(TablesCollection) {
    var t = new TablesCollection(null, {url: 'main-contact'});
});
```

passing in the URL, just as you'd like ... almost.  See there's one last issue, which is that your collection doesn't know to use the URL from the options; let's fix that:

```
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.url = options.url;
            this.fetch();
        }
```

With that you should be all set (but post back if there's any confusion).

Comment: @sehummel Note this [thread about rerunning factory function on AMD-spec mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/amd-implement/IPpUuSV3OII/discussion) It is possible that factory functions will be rerun if user makes a mistake of calling it under different ID. The issue user has was his `tableCollection` variable was redefined. It was not AMD's fault. I don't know what it is, but the caching of `tableCollection` model definition was one way to guarantree that it's not redefined by accident.

Comment: @machineghost-- does the `url` of `main-contact` get swapped out when a new `url` is assigned dynamically like in the section block of code?

Comment: Is it proper styling to capitalize the first letter of my models, views and collections, like classes?

Comment: @sehummel The way all Backbone properties work (including URL) is that the use the *instance* value, if any has been set, and if not they fall back to the *class* value.  In this case 'main-contact' would be the "class" (or "default") value for the property, so yes it would get replaced if the user calls `someTablesCollection.url = whatever` ... and you may notice that's exactly what I did with the line `this.url = options.url;`.  If for some reason you don't want `TableCollection` to use its `url` argument, just delete that line.

Comment: @seummel "proper" is subjective; JS has less truly "canon" formatting rules than a language like say Java.  That being said, there are semi-canonical rules (eg. Google's) and most if not all of them do recommend capitalizing all *constructors* (ie. functions that make new objects, ie. functions that are used with the `new` keyword, eg. `new Foo()`).  Since Backbone Collection/Model/View classes are such functions, it's common convention to capitalize them.